# How to get a Json Response after saving a data in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

how can I get a response after I created a data? So I want is when is saves. it show it's response, maybe in messagebox? Is it possible do it?

This is my controller code in saving..

```
 [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Create(FormCollection formCollection, string fn, string ln , ParentModel apsp)
    {
         string username = "sa";
         string apiKey = "sa";
         string baseUrl = "https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com";
         var settings = new PaySimpleSdk.Models.PaySimpleSettings(apiKey, username, baseUrl);

         var paymentService = new PaymentService(settings);


        fn = apsp.Customer.FirstName;
        ln = apsp.Customer.LastName;
        string street1 = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1;
        string street2 = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2;
        string city = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.City;
        Enum statecode = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode;
        Enum country = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.Country;
        string zipcode = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode;

        string credit = apsp.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber;
        string expir = apsp.CreditCard.ExpirationDate;
        Enum issuer = apsp.CreditCard.Issuer;

        decimal amount = apsp.Payment.Amount;
        string ccv = apsp.Payment.Cvv;

        var customerPayment = new NewCustomerPayment<CreditCard>
        {                             
           Customer = new Customer()
             {
                    FirstName = fn,
                    LastName = ln,
                    BillingAddress = new Address
                    {
                        StreetAddress1 = street1,
                        StreetAddress2 = street2,
                        City = city,
                        StateCode = (StateCode)statecode,
                        Country = (CountryCode)country,
                        ZipCode = zipcode
                    }
             },
           Account = new CreditCard
             {
                    CreditCardNumber = credit,
                    ExpirationDate = expir,
                    Issuer = (Issuer)issuer
             },
            Payment = new Payment
             {
                    Amount = amount,
                    Cvv = ccv
              }
        };

        var newCustomerPayment = await     paymentService.CreateNewCustomerPaymentAsync(customerPayment);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

The function of creating a data is from the SDK and the model itself

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: Yes, I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Create action should return `JsonResult` instead of redirect. But you will  need to use AJAX when calling Create action.:

   ```
   public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Create(FormCollection formCollection, string fn, string ln , ParentModel apsp)
   {
      /// your code for creating object
      return Json(newCustomerPayment, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```

   on the client side use `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html.BeginForm`

   ```
   using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", Home , new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "customerPaymentCreatedSuccess" }))
   {
   }

   <script>
       function customerPaymentCreatedSuccess(response)
       {
           alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. Use Post/Redirect/Get pattern. Once new payment is created, store it in TempData
   and return redirect as you currently do:

   ```
   TempData["newCustomerPayment"] = newCustomerPayment; 
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
   ```

   Then in Index Action check if there is anything in TempData and if there is, pass it to the view

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var customerPayment = TempData["newCustomerPayment"] as NewCustomerPayment;
       if(customerPayment != null)
       {
          ViewBag.customerPayment = customerPayment; 
       }
       //other code..
   ```

   }

Index view - generate JavaScript code to display customerPayment:

```
@{var customerPayment = ViewBag.customerPayment as NewCustomerPayment;}
@if(customerPayment  != null)
{
    <script>
        alert("@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerPayment ))");
   </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks I try the option one,it works fine.. how can I just put it in message box?

Comment: What is message box? There is no message box tag in HTML... Can you show an example of how it looks like?

Comment: it's like when you're saving , when you clicked the button a message box will appear that said do you want to save? but in my case after saving it will message the response

Comment: this sounds like an `alert` that I used in  my code. Or you can use some external library that allows you to show notifications. https://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/ for example

Answer (score 2):

To show an feedback of your of your operation you could return a JsonResult from your method and make the call and create the message box browser-side via Javascript.

Actions to take

1)change ActionResult to JsonResult in method definition

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<JsonResult> Create(FormCollection formCollection, string fn, string ln , ParentModel apsp)
```

2)change the return to something like:

```
return this.Json(message)
```

3)make your call to the method using ajax an create the message box on the callback method

Comment: what is this message?? in the second step

Comment: It is pseudocode. Message could be a simple string to be rendered in the message box or a more complex object to be processed browser side.